# Derivation of acceleration in circular motion. Why does Δθ = (Δv)/v?

Tags: orbital-motion

[image]

the equation on the left corner of the second page. can anyone explain to me? tq.

Comment: Two facts: i) for small angles $\theta$, $\sin{\theta}\approx \theta$; ii) very narrow triangles are approximately right-angle triangles, so sine $\approx$ opposite/hypotenuse.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to see this, but it's essentially due to the little figure of the triangle, with the angle labeled $\Delta \theta$ and sides labeled $v_A$, $v_B$, and $\Delta v$. If that triangle is very small, it is approximately a right triangle and you can write

$$\sin(\Delta \theta)=\frac{\Delta v}{v}$$

Well,  if $\theta$ is very small, we also have that $\sin\theta \approx \theta$ ("the small angle formula"). Applying this to the above we get the result you are interested in:

$$\Delta \theta=\frac{\Delta v}{v}$$.